# Create a new video post in blogger using api v3

Tags: blogger, google-api-php-client

This is how, I'm creating a new post to my blogger blog.

```
public function upload($file, $path, $title, $description)
{
    $video_file = WWW_ROOT . '../' . $path . $file;

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($this->GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($this->GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setAccessToken($this->access_token);

    $postData = new \Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
    $postData->setTitle($title);
    $postData->setContent($description);

    $service = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);
    $new = $service->posts->insert($this->blogger_id, $postData);

    if ($new) {
        $response['status'] = true;
        $response['video_id'] = $new->getId();
        $response['video_url'] = $new->getUrl();
    } else {
        $response['status'] = false;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

This is creating a new post with title and content fine. But, How should I use this to create a post with video `$video_file`

I don't want to use youtube and embed video code here. I want to use the video upload feature of blogger.

Comment: Blogger's Video Upload API is not public. You will have to resort to using the YouTube API ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert ) and then using the embed code to add that video into a new post

Comment: What if I don't want to use youtube for that?

Comment: That is totally up to you. If you have some other place where you can store the video files, you use that and then use the `<video>` tag to embed them into the new post